# Why is .Net Core 2.2 now publishing a ton of other dlls

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.2

I just upgraded my .net core 2.0 project to 2.2. To my knowledge, I didn't change any other settings, but now when I publish to my file system, it publishes a ton of folders and dlls that it didn't before.

Do I need to publish them? If not, can I suppress their output?

Here is my publish profile settings:
[image]

Here is what the output directory looked like before the upgrade:
[image]

Now, here is just a snippet of what the output directory looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Introduction: This issue seems to result from .net core 2.0.

From the picture you shared above. I know you choose Framework-Dependent Mode.

In this mode, generated files should be like what you have in picture1. And if your choose self-contained mode, generated files should be like what you have in picture2.

But in .net core2.0, there seems to be some different. When we publishing projects in .net core2.0, or just upgraded from 2.0 like yours. We must set self-contained property to false explicitly so that the Framework-Dependent mode can work normally.

> Do I need to publish them?

No, you don’t need to publish generated files from self-contained mode as you choose framework-dependent mode.

> If not, can I suppress their output?

Here is one workaround:

Looks like you use VS IDE to publish it, when publishing make sure choose 'create profile'. So we will have a PublishProfile, we can find it below Properties in Solution Window. Open the FolderProfile.pubxml and add the `<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>true</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>` in the `PropertyGroup`. Also, we can set the `<DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>` to true.

After that, publish the project again the issue can be resolved.

The final format of PublishProfiles looks like below:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>true</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

In addition: You can find more info from [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9852). Thanks to natemcmaster. His advice do work at my side.